# Updating MYSQL database OOP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, phpmyadmin

I recently created a website.  I followed some guides to get Login Registration with Email Verification, Forgot Password using PHP.  (LINK [Login Registration with Email Verification, Forgot Password using PHP. PDO OOP](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html))

NOW I want them to be able to select a number from 0-9999 and then save this value to a column in the users database.  I am stuck as to how to do this.

Here is a picture of the layout and some settings I have so far.

[AS YOU CAN SEE, I JUST NEED THE INPUT FIELDS SAVED TO THE CORRECT COLUMN LIKE I HAVE THE FIRST ONE OWRATING WHEN THE SAVE BUTTON IS PRESSED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxE64.png)

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Don't put picutres of code, add your *actual* code here as formatted text. And asking for code is off-topic for this platform.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thought it would be the easiest way to get the whole idea in one picture.  I didn't know I was asking for code, I was unsure where I made my mistake in my code.  I will refrain.  Thanks again

Comment: LESS YELLING AND MORE PUTTING OF THE SOURCE CODE IN THE QUESTION.

Comment: qmatches.com
I've got everything BUT the UPDATE PDO working.

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to give a `name` attribute for your `<input>` form fields. This name is how you will fetch the value.

```
<input type="number" name="owrating" value="0">
```

How to get a value from a form submission:

```
$owrating = (int) $_POST['owrating']
```

How to update a MySQL table with the value:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET owrating = :owrating WHERE id = :userID";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['owrating'=>$owrating, 'userID'=>$userID]);
```

Please get into the habit of using query parameters instead of copying PHP variables into your SQL strings. If you put your code on the internet, you need to learn how to defense against SQL injection attacks. You might like my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies).

Comment: Thank you.  Here is my updated pastebin.
Hopefully I got it correct.

http://pastebin.com/LMfibM0H

Comment: Sadly now I get this.
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: Oh, wow, that presentation is full of things that make me laugh and cry. Nice work.

Comment: @KyleO'Neil, you haven't set any values for `$username`, `$password`, or `$userID`. I think you have some more studying and tutorials to do. Stack Overflow is not an efficient way to learn the basics of programming.

Comment: Yes i'm sorry I am very new to this.  Second day really.  I thought if the person is already logged in that those are already in some kind of session.  And i'm simply updating the specified column by the current username and password and userID.

Comment: seems to be working now thanks i did what you said.  sorry for rushing into it.